# HTML5 - text input with padding is too wide

Tags: css, html, html4

I want an `input` field which will be padded from inside. I'm transferring to HTML5. I have it working in HTML 4.01 Transitional, but in HTML5 the `input` field started to go out of table frame. Can you help me correct it for HTML?

**Part of HTML Code**

```
<td class="content_listing_r" style="width: 80%;">
    <input type="text" name="model_search" style="width: 100%; padding: 5px"  autocomplete="off" />
</td>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

But should be looking like this:

[image]

Here's a fiddle for you to check out and play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/kelu/DbXy5/5/

Comment: padding adds extra width

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this CSS [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) rule to your input field:

```
.content_listing_r input {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/DbXy5/12/)**

Comment: I think that's it, I'm gonna check it out on all browsers, thank you!

Comment: Updated. Needed to add the -moz prefix for FF.

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter, care to comment as to the problem with the answer?

Answer (score 5):

Use `box-sizing: border-box`

```
    <input type="text" name="model_search" style="width: 100%; padding: 5px; box-sizing:border-box"  autocomplete="off" />
```

with vendor prefixes

```
box-sizing:border-box;
webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

[box-sizing : border-box](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Addition: ( If I may, (Royi))

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Android ≤ 2.3, iOS ≤ 4 */
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox 1+ */
          box-sizing: border-box; /* Chrome, IE 8+, Opera, Safari 5.1 */
```

Comment: Hey, this is the same answer as j08691 suggested I think and still the same issue - doesn't work on firefox for me.

Comment: @KeluThatsall  See the vendor prefixes version for FF fix

Comment: Thanks Royi for additional info!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.content_listing_r input {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the padding to the class "content_listing_r" instead of the input area, this will add padding around the cell.

```
<td class="content_listing_r" style="width: 80%; padding: 5px;">
    <input type="text" name="model_search" style="width: 100%"  autocomplete="off" />
</td>
```

Alternatively, make the width smaller, and add padding as a percentage

```
<td class="content_listing_r" style="width: 80%;">
    <input type="text" name="model_search" style="width: 96%; padding: 2%"  autocomplete="off" />
</td>
```

Comment: but will increase its own width

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately it's not what I was looking for. This won't make my input field bigger (the text inside is needed to be padded)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the handy `calc` rule for css width:

`<input type="text" name="model_search" style="width: -webkit-calc(100% - 10px); width: calc(100% - 10px); padding: 5px"  autocomplete="off" />`

...though it may have compatibility issues in less-popular browsers

Comment: Hey, your solution works so I'll give it a plus, but I think `box-sizing: border-box` is much better option. Also in your solution there is a problem, that the space to the right is a little smaller than it should be (but acceptable).

Comment: I agree - `border-box` seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If the input field is inside the thing, then you can use a width!

When you add `padding` it adds some little bit width and height depending on the parameters. You are using `100%` width and adding some paddings. Which is the issue!

Try this:

```
width: 96%;
```

Lessen the width a bit of the input, it will give you with the element you want! :)

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/DbXy5/8/

Comment: It will look different for every different container width - so that's a no-no. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

The padding adds extra width, if you change

```
padding:5px;
```

to

```
padding:5px 0;
```

it will fix your problem by removing the extra width while preserving top and bottom padding.

Comment: You are right, but your solution will make the input text start just from the border and I want a little space between text and the border to the left.